# In the latest launched AppInventor is it necessary to connect a phone to PC for building the app?

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have downloaded the appinventor_extras_setup.exe from net and installed the complete package. But whenever I type the URL http://appinventor.googlelabs.com it starts asking a survey.. Is that because I haven't connected my phone with the PC.. What if I m a developer with an android phone.. can't I use appInventor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://appinventor.googlelabs.com is taking applications to get involved with App Inventor. It is in a limited beta release right now. I and others are waiting patiently for our opportunity to play with App Inventor, as Google processes the invitations.

If you downloaded `appinventor_extras_setup.exe` from anywhere other than http://appinventor.googlelabs.com, it may not be an authorized copy.

> Is that because I haven't connected my phone with the PC

It is probably because you are not part of the beta program.

> What if I m a developer with an android phone.. can't I use appInventor?

Fill in the survey and wait to join the beta program.

Answer (score 2):

Now that some time has passed ;-)

The App Inventor invites are getting processed pretty fast.

You do not need an Android phone. There is an emulator that does a lot.

I use the emulator that comes with the Android SDK from Eclipse rather than the one you install if you follow the installation instructions for AI.

Answer (score 1):

It's not open yet. You need to register to it, and they may send you an invite to the beta when it starts.

The header to the "survey" is pretty clear:

**« We will be granting access to App Inventor for Android over the coming weeks. Fill out this form (only your Gmail address is required) and we’ll have you building apps soon!  »**

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to have your Android phone attached to use the appinventor app and to use appinventor at this time you need to be part of the beta

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers, but it stated that you need an Android device to be able to download the applications to.